# Rails 4 rspec 3 testing before validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I am trying to build a spec to make sure duplicate companies are not created.  When I used the following spec the company is properly assigned, however the factory still creates 3 companies.  This is not the desired behavior.

How would I adjust this spec to meet the criteria for the before validation call back?

**Spec**

```
  describe 'before validation' do
    it 'prevents duplicate companies' do
      company = create(:company)
      job1 = create(:job, company: company)
      job2 = create(:job, company: company)

      binding.pry
    end
  end
```

**Model**

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  before_validation :find_company

  ...

  private 

  ...

  def find_company
    existing_company = Company.where(email: company.email) if company
    self.company = existing_company.first if existing_company.count > 0
  end
end
```

**Factory**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :job do
    category
    company
    title { FFaker::Company.position }
    location { "#{FFaker::Address.city}, #{FFaker::AddressUS.state}" }
    language_list { [FFaker::Lorem.word] }
    short_description { FFaker::Lorem.sentence }
    description { FFaker::HTMLIpsum.body }
    application_process { "Please email #{FFaker::Internet.email} about the position." }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the transient block to make this work...

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :job do
    category
    transient do
      company
    end
    title { FFaker::Company.position }
    location { "#{FFaker::Address.city}, #{FFaker::AddressUS.state}" }
    language_list { [FFaker::Lorem.word] }
    short_description { FFaker::Lorem.sentence }
    description { FFaker::HTMLIpsum.body }
    application_process { "Please email #{FFaker::Internet.email} about the position." }
  end
end
```

**Spec**

```
  describe 'before validation' do
    it 'prevents duplicate companies' do
      company = create(:company)
      job1 = create(:job, company: company)
      job2 = create(:job, company: company)
      expect(Company.all.count).to eq(1)
    end
  end
```